# How to detect Windows path at end of which is NO FILES

Tags: java, directory-structure

I've had to create my own Windows backup program. It works well, but needs this improvement:

```
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\res\test> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\res\test\debug> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\debug> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\debug\lib> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\debug\obj> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\test> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\test\debug> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\test\debug\lib> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\rs\test\debug\obj> created 
++++++++++++ <C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Y\app\build\intermediates\symbols> created
```

It creates empty folders, which makes sense in that, if item `X` exists in the source and NOT in the destination, it should be created.

But I don't want all those empty folders.

I'm using

```
TreeWalker tw = new TreeWalker(); 
Files.walkFileTree(UserIO.inputPath, tw);
```

to "walk the file tree" from user's source node.

I was thinking about using *another* `TreeWalker` for any source item that is a folder, walking that tree, and NOT copying it (or any of its subfolders) if there are no files found anywhere on that "sub walk".

This nested `FileWalker` seems iffy (it would be called many, many times, may be unsafe or time-consuming), so I was wondering if there's a better/safer way, like maybe an external source (such as Apache commons) that counts non-folder files in a path, or maybe I should  use `nio` methods.

What to do?

(a) another `FileWalker`

(b) `nio` methods

(c) some already-existing method

(d) let the empty folders be created and go enjoy the rest of today

Comment: Empty folders have their use, say for error logging/crash dumps/caches. On `postVisitDirectory` you know whether the directory is empty.

Comment: Thanks, @JoopEggen--A vote for (d) but a vote for just deleting the empty directory when detected during normal walk, which cascades backward... at least I think that's the idea. Will consider both. In this order: I'm outta here, (Later: cascading delete possibility; probably just leave well enough alone, as is.)